# Wrong color of background in overflow menu

Tags: android, menu, background

I have a problem with the overflow menu in my Android app. I would like it to be white to fit in the overall theme.

At the moment it looks like this(API 22):

[image: OverflowMenu]

> I have two themes.xml.

The default one looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

> And one for API 21:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

From my understanding the themes.xml for API 21 should also be applied to every API level bigger than 21.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Try setting

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```

---

Create Overflow theme and add like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
     <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/AppTheme.Base.PopupMenu</item>
</style>
```

---

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base.PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Than you. With the solution provided I can change the background color. But this comes with the downside of breaking the material design guidelines. The overflow menu is now below the Toolbar and not anymore above it as it should be.

Comment: We are getting closer :) I reverted the changes and only set the theme on the Tooldbar widget. Saldy it let to the next issue. The text in the toolbar and the overflow menu icon(the three dots) are now black instead of white.